# 'mvn site' fails unless I've already run 'mvn install'

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

As the title says, I'm unable to generate a site unless I run 'mvn install' first. Also, note that 'mvn install site' doesn't work either. The two goals have to be run separately.

This is a multi module project.

If it's possible (and I'm sure it is) I would prefer to do this in one command from our jenkins server. Even more preferably without install, just 'mvn verify site'.

When I run

> mvn clean verify site

I get this error at the root module, before any of the submodules have been built.

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.4:site (default-site) on
>   project X: failed to get report for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin: Failed to execute goal
>   on project something-domain: Could not resolve dependencies for
>   project something:something-domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following
>   artifacts could not be resolved:
>   something:something-services:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
>   something:something-services:jar:tests:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
>   artifact something:something-services:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in
>   third-party-snapshots
>   (`http://local-nexus-mirror/content/groups/third-party-snapshots/`)

Comment: Are you doing the maven site only on one child project?

Comment: It's possible that one of your reports requires some of the artifacts from the build to be generated, and that the goals to generate them aren't tied into your site lifecycle. Perhaps you could provide the list of reports you have configured in the pom.xml, and also provide the error message?

Comment: @gerardribas no, this is done on the root of the project.

Comment: @MartinEllis the current error is that site fails for the root module due to unresolved dependencies to one of the submodules. This is while creating the javadoc report. But none of the submodules have been built yet.

Comment: This duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120594/failed-to-resolve-artifact-when-i-run-mvn-deploy-site-deploy-but-works-fine-if